# remove/list duplicates by comparing multiple lists in python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I know that remove/list duplicates in a list was already asked. I am having a problem with making it adopt to comparing multiple lists at the same time.

```
lst = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5]
a = [1,2,1,5,1]
b = [2,0,2,5,2]
c = [0,1,0,1,5]
```

if these were my lists i want to compare them as if i was using a zip function. i want to check if in list a indexes 0, 2 and 4 are duplicates if those same indexes are duplicates for other lists so for example in list b 0, 2 and 4 are also duplicates but in list c 0 and 2 are the only duplicates thus i want to only list indexes 0 and 2 from lst getting a result list [item1, item3]

How would i adopt this def to do that?

```
def list_duplicates(seq):
  seen = set()
  seen_add = seen.add
  # adds all elements it doesn't know yet to seen and all other to seen_twice
  seen_twice = set( x for x in seq if x in seen or seen_add(x) )
  # turn the set into a list (as requested)
  return list( seen_twice )

a = [1,2,3,2,1,5,6,5,5,5]
list_duplicates(a) # yields [1, 2, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to determine what common indices contain duplicate values across multiple lists, rather than  track the duplicate values themselves. That means that in addition to tracking the items duplicated in a given `seq`, we also need to track which indices the duplicated items were found. This is pretty straight foward to add to the existing method:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def list_duplicates(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_twice = set()
    seen_indices = defaultdict(list)  # To keep track of seen indices
    for index, x in enumerate(seq):  # Can't use a comprehension now, too much logic in there.
        seen_indices[x].append(index)
        if x in seen:
            seen_twice.add(val)
        else:
            seen.add(val)
    print seen_indices
    return list( seen_twice )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = [1,2,3,2,1,5,6,5,5,5]   
    duped_items = list_duplicates(a)
    print duped_items
```

This outputs:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [0, 4], 2: [1, 3], 3: [2], 5: [5, 7, 8, 9], 6: [6]})
[1, 2, 5]
```

So now we are tracking all the indices of duped values, in addition to the duped values themselves.

The next step is to apply this across multiple lists somehow. We can take advantage of the fact that once we've iterated across one list, we'll have eliminated a bunch of indices which we know aren't pointing to duplicated values, and only iterate over known-duplicate indices in subsequent lists. This requires reworking the logic a little bit, to iterate over "possibly duplicate indices" rather than over the entire list:

```
def list_duplicates2(*seqs):
    val_range = range(0, len(seqs[0]))  # At first, all indices could be duplicates.
    for seq in seqs:
        # Set up is the same as before.
        seen_items = set()
        seen_twice = set()
        seen_indices = defaultdict(list)
        for index in val_range:  # Iterate over the possibly duplicated indices, not the  whole sequence
            val = seq[index]
            seen_indices[val].append(index)
            if val in seen_items:
                seen_twice.add(val)
            else:
                seen_items.add(val)
        # Now that we've gone over the current valid_range, we can create a
        # new valid_range for the next iteration by only including the indices
        # in seq which contained values that we found at least twice in the 
        # current valid_range.
        val_range = [duped_index for seen_val in seen_twice for duped_index in seen_indices[seen_val]]
        print "new val_range is %s" % val_range
    return val_range

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = [1,2,1,5,1]
    b = [2,0,2,5,2]
    c = [0,1,0,1,5]
    duped_indices = list_duplicates2(a, b, c)
    print "duped_indices is %s" % duped_indices
```

This outputs:

```
new val_range is [0, 2, 4]
new val_range is [0, 2, 4]
new val_range is [0, 2]
duped_indices is [0, 2]
```

Which is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Search for duplicates on this list

```
l = [[a[i],b[i],c[i]] for i in range(len(a))]
```

for your example, it would produce this list:

```
[[1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1], [1, 2, 0], [5, 5, 1], [1, 2, 5]]
```

then:

```
result = [lst[i] for (i,x) in enumerate(l) if x in list_duplicates(l)]
```